# Calculating Tukey HSD following a repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons, post-hoc, tukey-hsd-test

I was wondering how to calculate Tukey's HSD to follow up a three-way repeated measures ANOVA by hand. I tried to infer how to do it by modifying what I would do in a between subject ANOVA, but I'm not sure whether I'm on the right path.

```
MSE = 18109  
n = 59 (I have a total of 59 subjects, which participate in all groups)  
df Error = 55
```

I'd like to make 4 comparisons using 8 means.

Using a `k` = 8 (should this be 4?) and the `df E` = 55 I looked up `q` = 4.45.  I divided 18,109 by 59 = 306, took the square root of it = 17.49 and multiplied it (17.49) by 4.45 = 77 = HSD.

Does this make sense?